# Travel status - Schengen

Tags: south-african-citizens

I live in Jersey Channel Island (South African passport). I'm married to a UK citizen but I have to keep applying every 3 months for a Schengen visa. Taking my residence into account, is there a way I can get around this? I have Leave to Remain.

Kindly advise please.

Comment: The only way to get around it, really, is to get a Schengen visa with a longer period of validity.  Have you ever asked for one?  How many Schengen visas have you held in the past?  Are your repeated travels to the Schengen area for the same purpose?